# Goldbach's conjecture in Haskell (99 questions #40)

Tags: haskell

I try goldbach's conjecture by haskell. This is 99 questions #40.
I copy and paste, then I got wrong result. Where do I fix? Would you give me advise please?
1 is not prime number.

```
Expect:
goldbach 14
(3,11)
or
(7,7)
Got:
goldbach 14
(1,13)
```

Question:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/31_to_41#Problem_40

Solution:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/40

My code:
Edited 2012-04-02 13:29 JST, **isPrime 1 = False**

```
I got:
goldbach 14
(3,11)
But I got:
goldbach 4
Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
Expected:
goldbach 4
(2,2)
```

https://gist.github.com/2233519

```
goldbach a = head $
                    filter (\(x,y) -> isPrime x && isPrime y) $
                    map (\e -> (e, a - e)) [1,3..a `div` 2]
  where
  factors a = filter (isFactor a) [2..a-1]
  isFactor a b = a `mod` b == 0
  isPrime 1 = False
  isPrime a = null $ factors a
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
[1,3..a `div` 2]
```

To

```
[3,5..a `div` 2]
```

I hope it makes sense why? Even though you exclude `1` from the `factors` function, you are still passing it in as a pair into the `map` function. So `isPrime` gets called with `1`. Let's see how it plays out:

```
isPrime 1 = null $ factors 1
```

and

```
factors 1 = filter (isFactor a) [] -- [2..1] == []
```

so

```
null (factors 1)
```

so

```
isPrime 1
```